# Nativescript with firebase plugin build error

Tags: firebase, nativescript

i have a problem with firebase plugin of nativescript;
i get this always when i build;

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzan
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzao
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip org.nativescript.plugins.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Project successfully built.
```

Comment: Is the Firebase messaging service working after the build? Check the Google Play version installed in your SDK and update to latest if possible. I have creted test project using firebase with GooglePlay Services ver.44 installed in my SDK https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/firebaseTest

Comment: i still get "successfully built" but with this :
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzan
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzao
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException